# Force In Store Pickup based on product attribute

Tags: multishipping

For regulatory reasons, some of our products must be shipped to an authorized receiver. We have a list of a few thousand authorized receivers.  Those items have a serial number and are closely tracked.  Sadly, when we ship non-tracked items to those authorized receivers, they rarely make it to the customer.

So, in the checkout process, we want to check for products with an assigned attribute, "restricted_shipping"

If the customer has such items in their cart, they will be required to use something like a store locator to select the shipping destination of the restricted items, AND enter the desired shipping address for any non-restricted items that tend to "fall off the truck" when sent to authorized receivers.

Shipping to the authorized receiver would be free, shipping of non-restricted items would be subject to the existing shipping methods, i.e. UPS, USPS ect.

We've looked at this from several angles, but I've yet to determine the best approach. I'd value insight on the different ways other developers would skin this cat.

Thanks!